# Python dictionary keys() Method

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out when the dictionary keys() method is mandatory. Here is my code.

```
rawFeats = [(0, 'mouse'), (1, 'black'), (0, 'cat'), (1, 'tabby'), (2, 'mouse')]
OHEDict = {(0, 'cat'): 1, (1, 'tabby'): 4, (2, 'mouse'): 5}
indices = {OHEDict[i]:1.0 for i in rawFeats if i in OHEDict}
indices1 = {OHEDict[i]:1.0 for i in rawFeats if i in OHEDict.keys()}

print "indices = {0}\nindices1 = {1}".format(indices, indices1)
```

the output is:

```
indices = {1: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0}
indices1 = {1: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0}
```

I can understand indices1 work well because `(0, 'cat')`is one of the keys, but why indices turn out the same result? Any hint will be appreciated. BTW, for large data set, indices's performance is way much better than indices1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On python2.x, `dict.keys` is (IMHO) more or less worthless.  You can iterate over a dictionary's keys directly:

```
for key in d:
    ...
```

which will be more efficient than iterating over the keys:

```
for key in d.keys():
    ...
```

which makes a separate list, and *then* iterates over it -- effectively doing the iteration twice + a bunch of extra memory overhead of having a throw-away list, etc, etc.

---

Your use-case is actually doing a membership test on the keys.  It's the difference between:

```
x in some_list  # is "x" an item in the list?
```

and

```
x in some_dict  # is "x" a key in the dictionary?
```

Membership tests on `list` objects are O(N) but on `dict` are O(1).  So, for every "turn" of the loop, you're doing an O(N) list construction and an O(N) lookup to see if the item is in the list instead of a simple O(1) hash lookup of the key.

It should be noted If you ever *do* actually need a list of a dictionary's keys, you could get it easily<sup>1</sup>:

```
list(d)
```

---

Fortunately, python3.x has taken steps in the correct direction.  `d.keys()` returns a `set`-like object in python3.x.  You can use this to efficiently calculate the intersection of two dictionaries' keys for example which can be useful in some situations.

It's also worth pointing out that the `set` like object in python3.x (called a `dict_keys` object) also has O(1) membership testing (as is to be expected of something that looks like a `set`), compared to the O(n) membership test of a `list`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This, consequentially, works in python2.x *and* python3.x so it's a nice thing to remember when you're trying to write code that is compatible with either...</sup>

Comment: Note that the code in the question isn't looping over the dict - it's performing a containment test. That makes removing the `keys` call dramatically more important.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Thanks,  I clearly didn't read the original post well enough.  I hadn't even noticed that it was being used in a membership test.

Comment: @user2357112 - Thanks, I didn't realize it s a containment test rather than an iteration. It makes sense on the 233k data set, the comprehension with keys runs for 38 mins, and another one just runs for 0.8 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Both refers (*iterate over*) the dictionary keys only.

```
for i in dic:
```

is equal to

```
for i in dic.keys():
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response.

Comment: While it's true that `for i in dic` has the same visible effects as `for i in dic.keys()` (as long as the dict doesn't change during iteration), the code in question performs a *containment* test, not iteration over the dict. Either way, using `keys` is less efficient, but for a containment test, `keys` is **exceedingly** inefficient, requiring time proportional to the size of the dict. It is crucial to take note of this.

Answer (score 0):

`x in dict` where `dict` is a python dictionary returns `True` if and only if `x` is a key for some entry in `dict`.

Comment: Thank you, I should read the method documentary more carefully.